# How can we compute the LAST page with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to implement pagination in my Servlet/EJB/JPA-Hibernate project, but I can't figure out how only one page from the query and know the number of pages I must display

I use

```
setFirstResult(int first) ;
setMaxResults(int max) ;
```

and that's working alright, but how can I know how many pages I will have in total?

(Hibernate is my JPA provider, but I would prefer using only JPA if possible)

UPDATE: COUNT() seems to be the better/easiest solution; 
but what can be the cost of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` in comparison with 
`executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ...).getListResult().size()` ?

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168084/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-of-making-pagination-in-hibernate-than-executing-se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to either (1) count or (2) retrieve the complete hit list and do pagination in-memory. The number of pages is the round up of the total count / the page size.

There are several ways to count, one is to use `COUNT(*)` like in

```
Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT
(emp.empName) FROM Employee emp");
```

or another oner is to use a projection

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
int rowCount = (Integer) criteria.list().get(0);
```

Note that I never used this one though, I just read it somewhere.

I had documented a few other details about pagination in this answer:

- [client side sorting + hibernate paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920209/client-side-sorting-hibernate-paging/1920509#1920509)

Hope it help