# Paging implimentation using Hibernate with Struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, paging

I am working on developing a paging solution using Hibernate as persistance layer and Struts2 as UI.
I was following the thread
[Similar Thread at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920209/client-side-sorting-hibernate-paging)

and it seems that the answers are themself good and explanatory,i still have some query,since i can have maximum of 2-3000 records (assuming 1-2K) so its still good approach to fetch all sorted records from db and place them in a cache and impliment paging functionality on the cache records or should be something like fetch few hundered records only.
we want paging functionality what SO have so i have already my logic to impliment this,only concern is should i fetch records from DB per page request or go for some other approach.

as a note this paging functionalty is for backend management.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch X records per page. Don't pull more than you need. Bozho's answer in that thread is best.

Are you having trouble implementing this?

Comment: no there is no problem in the implimentation,ny concern was since i do not going to have a large database for the implimentation so should i go for caching option or not.

Comment: Ah, ok. I would stick with the per-page approach.